# Website - Not Showing Index

Tags: php, html, url

Ok, I am very new to web development, so excuse that. I set up my webserver using a Linode Stackscript (LAMP). However, my webpage doesn't display my actual index.php file, instead, it displays http://www.imgbomb.com/i/?lBqKe. Why is this? My index.php is inside my www. When I type /index.php after the url, I get a *the page you are looking for is not found*.

Comment: Yeah, LAMP is set up fine. It's just that I get an index of thing.

Comment: Here's the location of index.php: /var/www/index.php

Comment: I use FileZilla using sftp. And you see that Index Of / when you go to the website: http://www.terabytic.com/

Comment: No errors whilst transferring files. If you want to help me I could give you my Teamviewer information and we could troubleshoot, but if it's too much trouble, I can just keep waiting :/

Comment: There is no way it is a server misconfiguration.. I have rebuilt (completely destroying all data and settings on vps) my Linode at least three times, all of them giving me this problem. Hmm..

Comment: What do you mean a bad time?

Comment: **@Syd** Did the answer of Milan solve the problem? If so, it would be great if you accept it. Also don't forget to clean up the comment mess here.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `DirectoryIndex index.php` to your .htaccess file or webserver configuration file.